# Pyqt5 transparent background but also interactable

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, drawing, transparent

So I'm trying to have a background that's interactable but also transparent. I want to be able to draw on the screen. As shown in the video below, if I use `self.background.fill(Qt.transparent)`, the background is not transparent like it's supposed to, it's black. But when I use `self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)`, I can't draw at all, and it's just interacting with the window underneath it. How do I make a transparent window but also being able to draw on it?

As seen, `self.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")` does nothing too. The background is still black

https://streamable.com/pjro9e

Here is my code:

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtCore import QPoint, Qt
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QPen, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from screeninfo import get_monitors


class Canvas(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.drawing = False
        self.lastPoint = QPoint()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        monitor = get_monitors()[0]

        self.setStyleSheet("background: transparent;")
        self.background = QPixmap(monitor.width, monitor.height)
        self.background.fill(Qt.transparent)
        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 1920, 1080)
        self.resize(monitor.width, monitor.height)
        # self.setWindowOpacity(0.5)
        self.setWindowFlags(Qt.Window | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint | Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), self.background)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = True
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        if event.buttons() and Qt.LeftButton and self.drawing:
            painter = QPainter(self.background)
            painter.setPen(QPen(Qt.magenta, 5, Qt.SolidLine, Qt.RoundCap, Qt.RoundJoin))
            # print(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            painter.drawLine(self.lastPoint, event.pos())
            self.lastPoint = event.pos()
            self.update()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if event.button == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.drawing = False


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Canvas()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `self.setStyleSheet('background:transparent)` with `self.setStyleSheet('background-color:transparent)`.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
self.setStyleSheet('''QMainWindow {background:transparent}''')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).